# Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :

Tags: 12.04, network-monitoring, aircrack-ng

I have setup a monitoring interface using:

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 channel 11
```

`sudo iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"" 
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: CC:B2:55:4L:3D:21
          Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm 
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:9  Invalid misc:101   Missed beacon:0
```

and the other interface:

`ifconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:5e:1k:f3:3b 
          inet addr:172.16.50.36  Bcast:172.16.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a3e:8eff:fe81:f31c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:425992 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61260 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:171687175 (171.6 MB)  TX bytes:9210579 (9.2 MB)
```

`sudo iwlist wlan0 channel`

```
wlan0     14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
```

`sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11`

```
Error for wireless request "Set Frequency" (8B04) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not permitted.
```

`sudo  iw dev wlan0 set channel 11`

```
command failed: Device or resource busy (-16)
```

`sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 11`

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
-e 
PID Name
1111    avahi-daemon
1112    avahi-daemon
1147    NetworkManager
1365    wpa_supplicant
9079    dhclient

Process with PID 9079 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0

Interface   Chipset     Driver
wlan0       Unknown     rt2800pci - [phy0]

                (monitor mode enabled on mon0)
```

What should I do and why I have this error?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Are you using `aircrack`? Could you edit your question and add more info.

Comment: no I usen't  @Sneetsher

Comment: what info you need and i can add @Sneetsher

Comment: How did you create/activate `mon0` interface?

Comment: sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 channel 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command used to setup `mon0` monitor interface should be enough to force monitoring that channel `11`.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 11
```

But your interface `wlan0` seem already connected to an access point. So `wlan0` is on that AP's channel `5`.

I suppose you have already get a note when starting `mon0` similar to this one:

```
Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!

PID     Name
875     avahi-daemon
883     avahi-daemon
982     NetworkManager
1183    wpa_supplicant
2081    dhclient
Process with PID 2081 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0
```

Well, you should disconnect and stop all those processes:

```
nmcli d disconnect iface wlan0

sudo service avahi-daemon stop
sudo stop network-manager
sudo pkill wpa_supplicant
sudo pkill dhclient
```

Then start monitor again:

```
sudo airmon-ng stop mon0
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0 11
```

Comment: @user4650183, updated answer

Comment: when i do this command i don't find wlan0 and I cant'connect to the network how can'I return after that I termin with mon0 my interface wlan0 :( I don't like to get out of network

Comment: @user4650183, Then you have to setup your WiFi AP to use same channel `11`, instead of `Auto` and leave those processes running. Another option is to use a second WiFi interface (USB adapter)

Answer (score 0):

You just only run ;

> `airmon-ng check kill`

That will kill all the annoying programs for Monitoring mode.