# Getting Error in Evil Twin Attack

Tags: 16.04

hello all I am very new to ubuntu.I have just downloaded aircrack-ng and tried to perform evil twin on my own network when I type the command `airbase-ng -a {MAC address} --essid {some essid name} -c 11 mon0` I got an error like this

```
Error: Got channel -1, expected a value > 0'.
```

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Check this post https://askubuntu.com/q/603477/26246 , may be there is a conflict with some running processes that uses same wireless interface

Comment: I tried that but getting same problem again